# Resources needed for class methods

Tags: c#, class, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does having lots of methods on a class increase the overhead of that class's object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441719/does-having-lots-of-methods-on-a-class-increase-the-overhead-of-that-classs-obj)

If I have a class:

```
public class Example
{
   int someInt1 = 0;
   ..
   int someInt10 = 0;

   string somestring1 = "1111";
   ...
   string somestring10 = "10101010";

   public Method1()
   {
      // do stuff
   }

   public Method2()
   {
      // do stuff
   }

   ...

   public Method10()
   {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

And I have the following:

```
Example Ex1 = new Example();
Example Ex2 = new Example();
...
Example Ex10 = new Example10();
```

It is clear to me that resources need to be allocated for each of the 10 int's and 10 strings in each class. Int's on stack, string pointers on stack, referenced to the heap (or so I believe).

I'm curious as to the methods contained in the class. Since this is compiled is there only one set of resources (memory I guess) used for the methods and then will this be shared between all instances of class 'Example' or will each instance chew up memory for the method code?

Comment: I think I just got the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441719/does-having-lots-of-methods-on-a-class-increase-the-overhead-of-that-classs-obj?rq=1

Comment: Just to clear up a misconception you have: Strings aren't references to the stack.. strings are reference types and are allocated on the managed heap. Stack-stored types (value types) have a fixed size.. strings don't.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of each Example instance is 4 pointers + 2 int = 24 bytes on 32-bit system. The strings are shared (referenced multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

in Java just one copy of each method in a class is stored, and all instantiated object can use that copy